# cohen kappa error (from psych r)

Tags: r, psych

I have data similar to so:

```
      id= c(1,2,3,4,5)
      question_A.1 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
      question_B.1 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
      question_C.1 = c(3,3,3,3,2)
      question_D.1 = c(4,4,4,2,1)
      question_A.2 = c(0,1,0,0,1)
      question_B.2 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
      question_C.2 = c(2,2,2,1,2)
      question_D.2 = c(4,3,1,3,4)
     test=data.frame(id, question_A.1, question_A.2, question_B.1,      question_B.2, question_C.1, question_C.2, question_D.1, question_D.2)
```

question_A.1 1 revers to person 1 answering question A. question_A.2  2 references person 2 answering question A
I have more observations and question/fields but the major jist is that I wanted to make do Cohen's kappa to find the reliability between the answers of the two question takers.

I run the following :

```
      cohen.kappa(test, w=NULL,alpha=.05)
```

AND I get the following error message:

```
   **Error in if (tr(w) > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
   In addition: Warning messages:
       1: In sqrt(Vark) : NaNs produced
       2: In sqrt(Vark) : NaNs produced**
```

This is basically identical to the one I get on my true dataset (except whatever NaNs produced is wasn't there)

Except I don't understand what the error is because these are number answers and I thought maybe there was missing values and that is why but I still get it with the tiny dataset. Can someone explain the error to me?

Answer (score 0):

Many measures of relationship are not defined in the case of no variance for one of the variables.  This is a reason to describe() your data before continuing to do more complex analyses.  Thus

```
    describe(test)
```

will flag the questions with no variances.
Three of the items in your example have 0 variance (A1 is all 1s, B1 is all 0s and B.2 is all 0s).  These are leading to the problems you experienced.

I have added a patch to psych 1.6.9 to complain about no variance for items rather than just obnoxiously quitting with a cryptic error message.